# How to sort Matrix

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization

I am on permutation project, and I have trouble with my result, the sequence of my result is not same with `Permutations` in Mathematica here the code

```
x[l_, elmn_] :=   Join[{h[l, elmn][[elmn - 2]]}, 
Reverse[ {h[l, elmn][[elmn - 1]] , h[l, elmn] [[elmn]]}]];

Table[{h[l, 3], x[l, 3]}, {l, 3}]
```

> {{{2, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 3}}, {{3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}}}

But the result on Mathematica `Permtations` is

```
Permutations[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}

I want to sort it to make it exactly same like `Permutations`

Comment: Is the intended question here that you want to `Sort` the lists at the bottom level in the input array? 

You say "short", but the result shown looks sorted.

If that's so, do you want to preserve the structure of the original array?

Comment: yes, i want the matriks array still on their position, like Permutations[{1,2,3,4,5}]. i am already have the matriks. but their posistion its so random

Comment: Can you check the brackets in the first line of code? With `list = {{2, 3, 4, 5, 1}, {2, 1, 5, 4, 3}, {3, 2, 1, 5, 4}}`, `Sort /@ list` does what I understand you want.

Comment: That structure also more closely matches what we would expect `Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]` to look like, and that was mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can change the answer you got into the same format as the output of Permutations. Start with your list, flatten, and sort:

```
list = {{{2, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 3}}, {{3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}}};
Sort[Flatten[list, 1]]

{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}
```